# React Link To not updating the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am using React with Redux to list number of items and inside the item I have a list of similar items

In Home Page (there is a list of items when you click on any of them , it goes to the item path ) which is working well , but inside the item page , when you click on any items from similar items list (the view not updating )

the [codeSandobx is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-johnson-ujym1)

App.js

```
const store = createStore(ItemsReducer, applyMiddleware(...middlewares));


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

main.js

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Header />

        <div className="container-fluid">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/item/:id" component={Item} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

Home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const itemsList = this.props.items.map(item => {
      return <ItemList item={item} key={item.id} />;
    });
    return <div className="items-list"> {itemsList}</div>;
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.items,
  user: state.user
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
  pure: false
})(Home);
```

Item.js

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      item_id: props.match.params.id,

    };


  }

  render() {

    const itemsList = this.props.items.map(item => {
      return <ItemList item={item} key={item.id} />;
    });
    return (
      <div id="item-container">

        <div className="item-list fav-items"> {itemsList} </div>;
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  items: state.items,
  user: state.user
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
  pure: false
})(Item);
```

and finally the ItemList.js

```
class ItemList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const item = this.props.item;
    const item_link = "/item/" + item.id;

    return (
      <Link to={item_link}>
        <div className="item-li">
                {item.title}
        </div>
      </Link>
    );
  }
}

export default ItemList;
```

I've tired to use [this solution](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux) from react-redux docs , but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect to update on link click?
Any path /item/:id (with any id: 2423, 2435, 5465) will show the same result, because you don't use params.id inside the Item component

**UPDATED**

When id changes the component doesn't remount, only updates component (It's correct behavior)
If you want to fetchData on each changes of id, the next solution has to work for you

on hooks:

```js
const Item = () => {
  const params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`/item/${params.id}`).then(...)
  }, [params.id]);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

useEffect will call fetch each time when id is changing

and in class component you have to use `componentDidUpdate`:

```js
class Item extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
      this.fetchData();
    }
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: it Item component , I use 

 item_id: props.match.params.id


then I use componentDidMount to fetch data about the item from items stored in the store

Comment: I am using componentDidMount already , kindly check this codesandbox , I put an example for the problem https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-johnson-ujym1?

Comment: @RemonAmin fixed your [sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-voice-b09iv)
if i helped you, mark please my answer as correct :)

Comment: Your solution helped me , but After I needed to make some modifications

Comment: Thank you SO SO SO MUCH!!! I was lost, about to spend my 3rd hour blindfolded changing code until I saw your componentDidUpdate. Have an awesome day and take the upvote.